# Error en el método POST con xmlhttprequest, No agrega el contenido

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

Estoy realizando un curso de xmlhttprequest y al aplicar el método POST y enviar los datos a mi archivo db.json no sales los datos que envío.

Aparece así el JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "keysel",
    "edad": 23
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nombre": "jesus",
    "edad": 26
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nombre": "flor",
    "edad": 50
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nombre": "keythleen"
  },
  {
    "id": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 7
  }
]
```

Este es mi archivo Ajax.js:

```
let lista_usuario = document.getElementById("lista");
let boton_enviar = document.getElementById("boton");

function reqListener(){
   const usuarios = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
   console.log(usuarios);
   const usuariosRender = usuarios.map(usuario => `<li>${usuario.nombre}</li>`).join("");
   console.log(usuariosRender);
   lista_usuario.innerHTML = usuariosRender;
}

var peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();
peticion.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
peticion.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/usuarios");
peticion.send();

function enviarDatos(){
   peticion.open("POST","http://localhost:3000/usuarios",true);
   peticion.setRequestHeader("Conten-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   peticion.send("nombre=Martha");
}

boton_enviar.onclick = enviarDatos;
```

Cuando presiono el botón enviar se ejecuta el POST, luego se renderiza y con innerHTML se agrega al DOM pero esta saliendo undefined en vez de los valores que yo coloco. Osea Martha.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El JSON que presentas al inicio sólo tiene los 4 nombres que ves, los últimos tres elementos no tieen campo nombre, por lo que tu código hace exactamente lo que se espera

Comment: Los primeros objetos del documento JSON ya vienen definidos en la API que cree para las pruebas. Los que están vacíos, son los que se agregaron con el metodo POST y deberian tener una propiedad "nombre = Martha"

Comment: Entonces el problema está en el lado del servidor, ese código parece hacer lo que se le pide. Si no añade más nombres es porque no están en la respuesta. Compruebalo mirando la pestaña de red de las herramientas de tu navegador